# Fcm background Notification in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented a notification in the backgound with firebase messaging. But, the problem is this; how can I return the data from the function myBackgroundMessageHandler to FirebaseNotification?

```dart
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      return Future<void>.value();
    }

    class FirebaseNotifications {
      FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging;
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

      void setUpFirebase() {
        _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
      }

      void fcmListeners() {
        _firebaseMessaging.configure(
          onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            print("OnMessage");
            processNotification(message);
            return;
          },
          onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
          onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            print("onLaunch");
            processNotification(message);
            return;
          },
          onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            print("onResume");
            processNotification(message);
            return;
          },
        );
      }

      processNotification(message) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is  a bug in the fireflutter library. you cannot access variables from your code, even if you used static or global variables.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1878

Answer (score 0):

I write a little program, which can permit to listen a background message push notification when your application is on background or terminated **(tested on Android only because I haven't iOS account)**.

This is the link to the repository
Click [here](https://github.com/akoua/Custom_push_notification_android)!

Comment: how do you implement it in yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the sharedPreference to save any data coming from the notification and access it within the app.
As the function is running on it's own isolate, it won't be able to access any static or global variable within the app.
Here's a demo:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
  RemoteMessage remoteMessage,
    ) async {
      String logicFlow = remoteMessage.data['logic_flow'];
      if (logicFlow != null) {
      if (logicFlow.isNotEmpty) {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setString('required_string', logicFlow);
    }
  }
}
```

After this: You can access the string from anywhere within your app using the same key that you used to store .i.e.

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String requiredString  = await prefs.getString('required_string');
```